# Background size with css with sprites

Tags: css, background-image, css-sprites

I have a list and each `<li>` has an icon and a text.

The image of icons is a sprite image, so I need to set the `background-size` of each `li` to have the size of an icon.

How can I do this with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the background image size in CSS3 like `background-size: 32px 32px;` but that is not really cross-browser compatible and I guess that is what your concern is.

Unless the sprite is well spaced out and vertical, my recommendation would be to use a bit of extra markup. For example, use markup like

```
<li><span class="ico"></span>This is an li element.</li>
```

and style the `span` element with appropriate height and background image sprite. Using this method, your `li` elements can have any height and only the appropriate icon would show up, despite how densely packed is your sprite.

Answer (score 4):

For images that support text - such as lists with icons - you would be better off using CSS pseudo-elements :before or :after. This keeps your HTML clean.

```
<ul>
   <li>List Item</li>
   <li>List Item</li>
</ul>

li:before
{
   content: "";
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   background: url("image.png") -12px -12px no-repeat transparent;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

For more details on this technique, check out http://css-tricks.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height. background-repeat of the LI as well as the padding.

Here is a handy tutorial: [preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists](http://preview.moveable.com/JM/ilovelists)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Swap place your sprite on the light gray area: http://jsfiddle.net/Pf7Xs/

Is this what you were asking? Having a sprite area and the text within an `<li>` of the same size?

You mostly will be using `line-height` and `height` to line up what you want.
hope that helps.